# what is error:expected an extended block and how could I fix it in my program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
#my first created softwre
name = 'Tariq'
myPassword = '765%^&'
if name == 'Tariq':
          print('Hi Tariq')
          myPassword = input()
          if myPassword == '765%^&':
          print('Hi creator')
     else:
          print("I don't know you strange")
          input()
```

It has an error that says `"expected an indented block"`.

I don't know what I should do I tried to add spaces among things which caused other errors that I fixed and I ended up with the first error.

Comment: You didn't indent the `print('Hi creator')` block enough...

Comment: python expects indentation after `:` character. Also general style guidelines should be 4 spaces per indententation level, it looks like you are double tabbing?

Answer (score 0):

This should work but may operate differently than you were intending:

```
# my first created software
name = 'Tariq'
my_password = '765%^&'
error = False
if name == 'Tariq':
    print('Hi', name)
    if my_password == '765%^&':
        print('Hi creator')
    else:
        error = True
else:
    error = True
if error:
    print("I don't know you strange")
input()
```